# How I can save file with script Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

I want to write a script that would substitute different text from a text file into my shalon and save the image in jpeg format.

An error occurs: "This function may not be available in this version of Photoshop" on this line:

```
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, jpgSaveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

My code:

```
while(!myFile.eof)
{
line = myFile.readln();
createText(line);

var thistimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
saveFile = new File( "/c/Users/marki/Desktop/Temp001/" +thistimestamp)
saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
saveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
saveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
saveOptions.quality = 9;
app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

I use Adobe Photoshop: 2017.0.0 20161012.r.53 2016/10/12:23:00:00 CL 1094006 ( x64)

Comment: You missed out the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed off the extension :D

```
 saveFile = new File( "c:\\temp\\" + thistimestamp) + ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking that your script `createFile()` is well defined and working, you are missing document creation command `app.documents.add()` before you start issuing commands. You are also missing file open procedures. When added, the code works fine:

```
function createText(fface, size, colR, colG, colB, content, tX, tY) {
  var artLayerRef = app.activeDocument.artLayers.add()

  artLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT

  textColor = new SolidColor();
  textColor.rgb.red = colR;
  textColor.rgb.green = colG;
  textColor.rgb.blue = colB;
  
  textItemRef = artLayerRef.textItem
  textItemRef.font = fface;
  textItemRef.contents = content;
  textItemRef.color = textColor;
  textItemRef.size = size
  textItemRef.position = new Array(tX, tY)
}

var myFile = new File("/c/temp/myfile.txt");
myFile.open('r');

while(!myFile.eof) {
    
    app.documents.add();

    line = myFile.readln();
    createText(line,10,2,2,2,line,10,10);

    var thistimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    saveFile = new File( "/c/temp/" +thistimestamp)
    saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
    saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
    saveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
    saveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
    saveOptions.quality = 9;
    app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

This code is tested with version 20.0.2 20181219.r.30 2018/12/19: 1202136 x64

The text file content is:

[image]

And the result in Photoshop is:

[image]

Of course, all three documents are saved as jpegs in c:\temp.

In case you don't have a working `createText` function, you can find an example in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280465/photoshop-script-to-create-text-in-a-bitmap-image-in-photoshop). The function in this example is taken from that article.